# My custom adapter isn't used by django-allauth

Tags: django, adapter, django-allauth

I'm using **django 1.6.5** and **django-allauth 0.18.0** and the social login works as expected once we create the social app in the django's admin panel.

So, my next step was trying to change the module's behavior by using adapters.

It looked simple in the [docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=adapter#creating-and-populating-user-instances)  but somehow, I can't seem to make **django-allauth** use my custom adapters.

So here's my attempt of trying to *pdb* into my adapter's methods.

here's my folders/files structure:

```
.
├── manage.py
├── requirements.freeze
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── foo_app
    ├── adapters.py
    ├── views.py
    ├── etc...
```

here's my *foo/settings.py* file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'foo_app'
)
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER="foo_app.adapters.FooAppAccountAdapter"
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER="foo_app.adapters.FooAppSocialAccountAdapter"
```

And here's my *foo_app/adapters.py* file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pdb

from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter


class FooAppAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=true):
        print "FooAppAccountAdapter.save_user"
        pdb.set_trace()
        return super(FooAppAccountAdapter, self).save_user(
            request, user, form, commit
        )


class FooAppSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        print "FooAppSocialAccountAdapter.pre_social_login"
        pdb.set_trace()
        return super(FooAppSocialAccountAdapter, self).pre_social_login(
            request, sociallogin
        )

    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        print "FooAppSocialAccountAdapter.save_user"
        pdb.set_trace()
        return super(FooAppSocialAccountAdapter, self).save_user(
            request, sociallogin, form
        )
```

None of my **set_trace** are working and I think I might just have forgot something in the settings but can't figure it out.

So what I am missing or doing wrong guys ?

Comment: I'll be digging into the module to find out what is happening. I'll post an answer if I stumble upon the solution.

Comment: Probably not directly related to your issue but `commit=True` not `commit=true`

Comment: @bchhun You ever figure this out?

Comment: @JonathanCox sadly, no :(

Comment: most likely your adapter was in an app that was listed after all-auth in your INSTALLED_APPS. Make sure to put it in an app that is listed before, and it should pick it up.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add 
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.users.adapter.MyAccountAdapter' 
to the setting.py

for more details on customising the adapter class, check this link https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects

Comment: In case this helps others. I followed instructions above but named my custom adapter file `account_adapter.py` which is seems to be reserved name so it was giving `ModuleNotFoundError`. I had to rename it to something else eg `my_account_adapter.py` and then this worked.